# Watch if local branch was switched

Tags: git

I have a project which uses git branches and a watcher that runs some tasks when files in the project change.

Sometimes I switch between branches and the watcher breaks occasionally because of it.

I think that it would be great to know exactly when a branch switch happens and ends.

How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: You could watch for changes of `.git/HEAD`

Comment: I would probably start with a different approach entirely, although this really depends on what you are watching *for* and *why*.  In general there is no alert from git when it starts and ends doing something to a work-tree.  In some *specific* cases, the file `index.lock` remains in existence for that period, so testing for it might handle your specific cases, maybe.

Comment: I think a hook named `post-checkout` can work here.